# counting date and time for historical reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am currently working on a query that will be used in junction with share-point to run reports.  I have a query that I know will work with Oracle, but the company I am working for is running SQL Server 2005.

What the report will do is give the person the ability to select any date and time, and give the count for that specific operation. The problem is that there are large gaps in the time stamps (because it takes a little while for the product to get to the next operation).  The date type is varchar, so i used substrings to parse out the year, month, day, and time.  I have [sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhNG3dN_hTHIdElnUnhMRkE3eFFYOGhRcC1QdzJtcHc) available.

The people looking at the reports want the ability to say at this time and day how many units went through this operation.

I know this is is confusing, let me know if you need any clarification.

Here is the oracle syntax

```
SELECT T3.PAYMENT_DATE, T3."Hr", T3."Min", 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM INVOICE_ARCHIVE T4 
        WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(T4.PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM')) <= T3."Hr" 
        AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(T4.PAYMENT_DATE, 'DD')) <= T3."Min") AS "NUM"
FROM(SELECT T1.PAYMENT_DATE, T2."Hr", T2."Min"
     FROM (SELECT (FLOOR((LEVEL + 359)/60)) AS "Hr", 
                  MOD((LEVEL + 359), 60) AS "Min"
           FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 961) T2, INVOICE_ARCHIVE T1
     ORDER BY T1.PAYMENT_DATE, T2."Hr", T2."Min") T3
```

Comment: When they want to see how many per day/hour, do they want a range, or rolled up to the chosen duration?  Please provide samples of your original table (or an appropriately anonymized version), because it's not clear what your base table is.  Separating out parts of date and time by converting to varchar is not the ideal solution - if you have an actual date type, there are better methods available.  Also, you should probably look into using CTEs, instead of inline sub-selects (for programmer performance reasons, not compiler ones).

Comment: This is a good question, i am glad you asked. From what i understand, they will be wanting a range. The range would start that morning at 6am and end at whatever time they selected. We have all of the historical data on another table but it only has information on the sum of the day. I think the course of action we are going to take now is to edit the java code to input the data we need (on a per hour basis) and export that to a separate table so that we are pulling all of the information from one table; we are also hoping that this will be a faster and less taxing on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is the datepart() function in SQL Server.  This will allow you to extract minutes and hours from dates.

The harder part is the "connect by level" portion.  How is this being used?  You might need to use recursive CTEs to handle this.

With the little hint from spencer, the following may suffice for your query:

```
SELECT T3.PAYMENT_DATE, T3."Hr", T3."Min",
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM INVOICE_ARCHIVE T4
        WHERE datepart(month, T4.PAYMENT_DATE) <= T3."Hr" AND
              datepart(day, T4.PAYMENT_DATE, 'DD') <= T3."Min"
       ) AS "NUM"
FROM (SELECT T1.PAYMENT_DATE, T2."Hr", T2."Min"
      FROM (SELECT top 961 (FLOOR((LEVEL + 359)/60)) AS "Hr",
                    MOD((LEVEL + 359), 60) AS "Min"
            FROM (select top 961 row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as level
                  from invoice_archive
                 ) t
           ) T2 cross join
           INVOICE_ARCHIVE T1
     ) T3
 ORDER BY T3.PAYMENT_DATE, T3."Hr", T3."Min"
```

I made the following changes:

1. Changed the date arithmetic to use datepart() instead of to_char() .
2. Replaced the method for getting a list of numbers, by using row_number() instead of connect by level
3. Made the cross join explicit
4. Moved the order by to the outer query, since neither SQL Server nor Oracle guarantee the results of an order by in a subquery (and SQL Server does not allow it unless you have a "TOP" query)

Comment: The "from dual connect by level" is used as a convenient way to generate 961 integer values: 1,2,3,...,961

Comment: This syntax seemed to do the trick as well 
   WITH Hr(Number) AS
(
    SELECT 6 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1
    FROM Hr
    WHERE Number < 22
),
Mn(Number) AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1
    FROM Mn
    WHERE Number < 59
),
HourMinute AS
(
    SELECT hr.Number AS [Hr]
        , mn.Number AS [Min]
    FROM Hr